# Generate control flow chart from ARM assembly

Tags: ios5, assembly, arm, flowchart, ida

Currently I have some ARMv7 assembly code extracted from iOS 5 App with the help of IDA Pro, I would like to generate a control flow graph based on those assembly code. Is anyone can recommend the tool can help me to do that? I have little knowledge of assembly, but I can learned basic instruction and concepts to build the graph

Thanks anyway!

Comment: The version of IDA is 6.3

Answer (score 1):

IDA generates those internally. Switch to Graph view.